# Flutter release build getting failed with 'Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, visual-studio-code, gradle

**Errors:**

```
  [Fatal Error] flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-f40e976bedff57e69e1b3d89a7c2a3c617a03dad.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
  [Fatal Error] flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-f40e976bedff57e69e1b3d89a7c2a3c617a03dad.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:generateReleaseRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_core:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-f40e976bedff57e69e1b3d89a7c2a3c617a03dad.
     Required by:
         project :firebase_core
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-f40e976bedff57e69e1b3d89a7c2a3c617a03dad.
         > Could not parse POM https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_release/1.0.0-f40e976bedff57e69e1b3d89a7c2a3c617a03dad/flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-f40e976bedff57e69e1b3d89a7c2a3c617a03dad.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          125.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried the followings:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter upgrade
flutter pub upgrade
```

and also did a:

```
gradle clean
```

Still I am getting the same error. Please help me out with a solution.